# data with specific length and characters in select query oracle

Tags: oracle

My table look like this in my oracle db;

```
ID | NI       | NT      | MB         |  ETC
-------------------------------------------
1  |1234567   |         |            | comments  //valid
2  |9654875   |         |            | jhdsd     //valid
3  |43gf543   |         |            | dd        //in-valid
4  |123       |         |            | dfds      //in-valid
5  |12654332  |         |            | dffd      //in-valid
6  |          |542      |            | comments  //valid
7  |          |362      |            | jhdsd     //valid
8  |          |9631     |            | dd        //invlaid
9  |          |r45      |            | dfds       //in-valid
10 |          |56       |            | dffd      // in-valid 
11 |          |         |03121234567 | comments  //valid
12 |          |         |03874514414 | jhdsd    //valid
13 |          |         |05764544444 | dd      //in-valid as not starts with 03
14 |          |         |30010101019 | dfds    //in-valid
15 |          |         |038f5678543 | dffd    //in-valid
```

I like select only valid records with select query

where

- NI length should be fix 7 and all, starts with any digit
- NT length should be fix 3 and all, starts with any digit
- digits MB length should be fix 11, starts with 03 and all digits.

result should look like this;

```
1  |1234567   |         |            | comments  
2  |9654875   |         |            | jhdsd    
3  |          |542      |            | comments  
4  |          |362      |            | jhdsd    
5  |          |         |03121234567 | comments  
6  |          |         |03874514414 | jhdsd
```

Comment: And what is your attempt? Show us your query you have come up with and tell us where you are facing the issue.

Comment: @KaushikNayak well I have tried with Length() function, but I don't know how to find a wor starts with 03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- NI length should be fix 7 and all, starts with any digit

  ```
  REGEXP_LIKE(NI, '^\d{7}$')
  ```
- NT length should be fix 3 and all, starts with any digit

  ```
  REGEXP_LIKE(NT, '^\d{3}$')
  ```
- digits MB length should be fix 11, starts with 03 and all digits.

  ```
  REGEXP_LIKE(MB, '^03\d{9}$')
  ```

Comment: just working for length, not starts with, show all results which starts with  digits other than 03

Comment: can I use anything else than {} ; like [] , because I am using this for taking input from my file in query `'^03\d[9]$'`

Answer (score 0):

you could use a substr  and length

```
  select ID, NI, NT, MB, ETC
  from my_table  
  where length(NI) = 7 
  and length(NT) = 3 
  and substr(MB,1,2) ='03'
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(NI, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(NT, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
```

Comment: how would length identifies only digits ?